# What exactly can I hinge the lack of rebellion of several conquered states on?

Tags: warfare, culture, religion

Culture and religion have always been a contributing factor in the mass control of humankind. Although, more so of the latter. I'm currently writing a novel wherein a particular nation arises with such a particular ambition of world domination. Said world is of course fictional but expectedly incorporates many aspects of our non-fictional world. 
During the era of Genghis Khan, fear was the outstanding reason for a lack of rebellion of several vassals, conquered kingdoms alike. Where a certain portion of a city/town's population was executed. Adding to this was the culture of rape perpetrated by the Mongolian army upon seize. Generally the invasion of any land would stir resent in their citizens. For world domination, I feel stirring fear in conquered states or vassals as a measure of control will only get so far. Napoleon's forces were disadvantaged because of a quite questionable military culture. The British empire, I would say was the most successful at world domination, used language and religion to secure their control.  However, the liberties the British allowed their conquered states became a bite too large to swallow. The talk of independence began and despite onset resistance, the British had realized their mistake. 
Alas! My question resurfaces, will a combination of fear, religion (although can be an aspect of fear - condemnation of sinners to hell in Christianity), and culture (military and/or otherwise) be the best measure of control for the ambition of world domination?
Or is there any other measure that will be more effective?

Comment: I wouldn't really blame the collapse the British granting to many freedoms. It was the two worldwars which weakened the great powers enough so they lost control of their colonial empires.

Comment: Yes, of course, but inherently, the freedoms allowed these nations to seek/push for independence. I feel actions as such build, not just spring up out of the blue.

Comment: Fear can work, but only so far.  When one has nothing to lose vengeance can overcome fear.  Of course uprisings can be suppressed, but when enough people have nothing left to lose, regardless of the tactics employed by those in power, they are far outnumbered by those they have offended.  Success is a much better motivator.  Consider when resources are limited by power struggles or defensiveness among separately ruled groups.  When a conqueror assimilates those groups and distributes the limited resource in a way that increases opportunity for all, then the majority couldn't disagree.

Comment: Subjugation ultimately serves to unify subjects in opposition to the subjugating ruler.  Conversely, loyalty serves to unify subjects in favor of a supportive ruler.  However, this only works if the rulers are careful not to allow their own greed to overcome the rational acquisition of power.  Also note that understanding such logistical dynamics, as describe in the previous comment, is information that serves in determining how to proceed when building an empire.

Comment: How many rebellions did the Romans have to put down throughout the long history of the Roman Empire? Was there *ever* any rebellion in Iberia, in Asia Minor, in Egypt, in Syria, in Greece, in Thrace etc.? Sometimes an empire is perceived as a good thing.

Comment: @AlexP well you have all those Judean Zealots, :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or is there any other measure that will be more effective?

Lots of methods work for a while.

For really getting rid of all chance of rebellion Moses and after him Joshua of the Israelite's had the most thorough method.

They just depopulated whole regions by exterminating the entire populations living there. Including regions they had no intention of occupying but didn't want a hostile population in to make future trouble. They even exterminated an ally of theirs.

Ghengis did similar things but his agenda was different so many cities survived as they were necessary. The Israelites didn't, surrendering didn't make a difference, they were not interested in slaves or anything else.

Comment: Thank you! The Israelites were quite brutal, but again, they were acting according to their religion. The executions were at most times instructions from God, to annihilate 'wicked' people's from the earth. I feel religion will be the strongest measure of control, only second to ruthless executions.

Comment: Soldiers follow leaders orders whether they say from God or not, Most leaders start talking about god early, even nowadays. Moses also exterminated a lot of his own people. Religion on it's own is prone to schisms, and most religions will happily commit atrocities on co-religionists. Israelites were a combination of racial and religious reasons.

Comment: I understand completely. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's let Britain itself answer this one... in film.

> Brian: People, we should be struggling *together*!
>
> People's Front of Judea fighter: *(wrestling with a Judean People's Front fighter)* We are!

(From Monty Python's *Life of Brian*.)

Rebels agree that they don't like the central government, but they don't necessarily agree on anything else. Political, religious, ethnic, or economic tensions will tend to split rebels into many different groups, and if they don't, cliques arising around charismatic (competing) leaders can do the trick. See also: the splits, divisions, factions, mergers, etc. etc. of the Communist parties of any given Western nation in the last 100 years.

And, of course, if the rebels aren't struggling together enough for the empire's sake, it can always stir the pot. Loosen the reins so people forget how bad the empire is supposed to be. Give them some amenities and luxuries ("but apart from the sanitation, the medicine, education, wine, public order...") and some political power to squabble over. Maybe favorable treatment towards one group will make others wonder if they've sold out. Maybe the promise of favorable treatment gets them to *actually* sell out. If it's still too quiet, send in the secret police as agent provocateurs to stir up trouble.

To be sure, this method has its drawbacks (it's hard to sell "here, have some political power and expensive luxuries, oh, and we'd like a 50% tax hike and new army levies" all at once), but combined with keeping a judicious eye on the state of affairs in different regions, you can do wonders to diminish the rebels' effectiveness and discredit them in the eyes of the public.

Comment: Thanks! The Human is a most complicated being. Now add millions, with diverging mindsets, and intricacies of traditions and cultures, and we have a melting pot of trouble.